# Circuit requirements for 'fixed' output switching regulator

Tags: switching-regulator

I am considering using one of these switching regulators in a circuit:

- TPS560430YFDBVR ( output type PWM )
- TPS560430X3FDBVT‎ ( output type 'fixed' )

The datasheet for both are the same thing:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps560430.pdf

The datasheet gives this example of a simplified schematic:

[image]

The feedback voltage divider R<sub>FBB</sub> /  R<sub>FBT</sub> can be used to adjust the desired output voltage.

The datasheet also says "Fixed 3.3-V Output Option". Presumably with a non-adjustable output the voltage divider is not necessary, so the circuit would be somewhat different. However I can't find any mention of how it should be arranged.

Should FB connect directly to V<sub>OUT</sub> in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes FB must be connected to output when using the fixed 3.3V version.